# Specify token options for OmniAuth OAuth2 based strategy

Tags: ruby, oauth, omniauth

I'm creating custom strategy for Nimble.com API. As they're using OAuth, it's pretty simple.

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Nimble < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, "nimble"

      option :client_options, {
        :site => "https://api.nimble.com",
        :authorize_url => '/oauth/authorize',
        :token_url => '/oauth/token'
      }

      # option :access_token_options, {
      #   :mode => :query,
      #   :param_name => :access_token
      # }      

      option :provider_ignores_state, true

      uid { raw_info['email'] }

      info do
        {
          'uid'   => raw_info['email'],
          'name'  => raw_info['name'],
          'email' => raw_info['email']
        }
      end

      extra do
        { 'raw_info' => raw_info }
      end

      def raw_info
        access_token.options[:mode] = :query
        access_token.options[:param_name] = :access_token        
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/users/myself/', {:parse => :json}).parsed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For passing tokens, they need to use access_token parameter in URL. When I specify options in raw_info function directly, as in sample — it's OK.

When I'm trying to specify this options in access_token_options hash (like in commented section) — parameters aren't passing to token. I'm not very good in Ruby, so I didn't figure out from libraries sources — how correctly pass parameters to access_token in OmniAuth OAuth2 descendants.

I'd like to make it "right way", so access_token initialised with correct options, plese someone point me the right way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've explored several existing strategies (GitHub, 4SQ), and looks like it's normal practice to directly modify access token options.

So I'll stay with it :)